# how to use zhmakeindex instead of makeindex in bookdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, chinese-locale, bookdown

in https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown. I find that in *./inst/example*, makeindex is much usefull for my book. I want to add Chinese index in my [book](https://github.com/bubifengyun/deepin-bible), but makeindex cannot work as expected for Chinese index.

I can compile index use `zhmakeindex` instead of `makeindex` without change the `tex file`, like the example in https://github.com/leo-liu/zhmakeindex.

as http://www.ituring.com.cn/article/207412 told.

`bash
xelatex -interaction=batchmode zhmakeindex.tex
bibtex zhmakeindex
zhmakeindex zhmakeindex
xelatex -interaction=batchmode zhmakeindex.tex
xelatex -interaction=batchmode zhmakeindex.tex`

How can I use `zhmakeindex` instead of `makeindex` in bookdown? I cannot find where to write `makeindex` or `zhmakeindex` command. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current development version of the **tinytex** package, you can set the global option `tinytex.makeindex` in your `.Rprofile` or an R code chunk in your book:

```
devtools::install_github('yihui/tinytex')
options(tinytex.makeindex= 'zhmakeindex')
```

Further command-line options can be passed via the global option `tinytex.makeindex.args`, e.g.,

```
options(tinytex.makeindex.args = c('-z', 'pinyin'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am testing, I find some problems, such as how to add zhmakeindex's option `-z pinyin` etc. When works well, I will come back.

Comment: typos, like your source code, it should be `zhmakeindex` instead of `zhmakeidx`

Comment: I have added support for further options via `tinytex.makeindex.args`. See my updated answer. Thanks for pointing out the typo!

Comment: I used another latex package `imakeidx`, which is more super than `makeidx` package, and the makeindex options can be add in tex file. Just test. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @yihui Here is my solution. full source code see https://github.com/bubifengyun/deepin-bible and I had find one bug in pandoc https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4762

in *./latex/template.tex* I add this code

```latex

```
\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=\titleindex,columns=2,intoc=true,columnseprule=true]
\indexsetup{
    othercode={%
        \thispagestyle{main}%
    }
}
```

```

in *./index.Rmd* to use zhmakeindex, I add this code

```R

```
options(
    htmltools.dir.version = FALSE, formatR.indent = 2, width = 55, digits = 4, tinytex.makeindex =  zhmakeindex, tinytex.makeindex.args = '-s imakeidx.ist'
)
```

```

here is result

[image]